# Ejecutar script generado con PHP despues de cargar AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

He puesto el siguiente codigo javascript de prueba pero no se ejecuta tras cargar la pagina con AJAX.

```
<script> alert('hi'); </script>
```

Mi codigo AJAX (en funciones.js):

```
function mostrarAJAX(enlace, elem)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: enlace,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() { $(elem).html('<br /><center style="margin- 
        top: 50px;"><span style="margin-right:8px;"></span><img 
        src="../images/loading.gif" /><div style="font-size: 20px;margin- 
        top: 25px;">Loading...</div></center>'); },
        error: function(xhr) { $(elem).html(xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText); },
        success: function(result){ $(elem).html(result); }
    });
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el AJAX, la pagina se muestra, pero no se ejecuta el script. La cosa es que parte del javascript lo genero desde PHP con echo, ya que es un grafico de estadisticas.

Trozo del javascript real (en stats.php):

```
data: 
[
  <?php
    $resultstats = mysqli_query($con, $sqlstats);
    $countstats = mysqli_num_rows($resultstats);
    for($i = 0; $i < $countstats; $i++)
    {
        $rowstats = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstats);

        if($i < ($countstats - 1))
            echo '{date: "'.$rowstats['Date'].'", value: '.$rowstats['TotalMembers'].'}, ';
        else
            echo '{date: "'.$rowstats['Date'].'", value: '.$rowstats['TotalMembers'].'}';
    }
    ?>  
],
```

El script PHP se ejecuta correctamente rellenando el array javascript con las estadisticas para el grafico pero el problema es que el javascript no se ejecuta, por lo que el grafico no se muestra. Cuando ejecuto el grafico sin AJAX, el grafico funciona correctamente.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Has probado con meter el código javascript en un onload?:
    <script>
      function load() {
        alert('hi');
      }
      window.onload = load;
    </script>

Comment: Qué es lo que querés ejecutar desde javascript? Lo único que veo que hacés ahí es insertar lo que viene de php al dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de enviar el codigo final, intenta enviando solo la data y luego en el cliente la intepretas y lo ejecutas.

Con tu ejemplo del `alert('hi')`, envia la respuesta del texto `hi` y muestralo con un `alert`:

En el php:

```
echo 'hi';
```

En tu js:

```
$.get(url, function(mensaje){
   alert(mensaje);
})
```

Podrias hacer lo mismo con los datos del grafico. Simplemente envia los datos y se lo agregas al grafico.

En tu php tendrias:

```
echo json_encode(data);
```

Y en tu js tendrias:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
   console.log(data); // [...]
});
```

Esto porque si envias el codigo como tal, tendras que interpretarlo con [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), algo que no es muy recomendado si no sabes manejarlo.

Comment: gracias Einer. Me ha servido :)

Answer (score 0):

Para quien le pueda ayudar, como el navegador no ejecuta los codigos javascript explicitos tras una llamada AJAX, he tenido que hacer lo siguiente:

stats.html:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/MemberStats.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="inicio-top-h1">Miembros Registrados</div>
<div id="TotalMembers" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div class="inicio-top-h1">Miembros Activos</div>
<div id="ActiveMembers" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div class="inicio-top-h1">Horas Online</div>
<div id="TotalTime" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div class="inicio-top-h1">Horas Online Semanales</div>
<div id="TimeWeek" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>

<div class="inicio-top-h1">Registros Semanales</div>
<div id="RegWeek" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

MemberStats.js:

```
function mostrarGrafico(columna)
{
$.get('GetStats.php', {column: columna}, 
    function(datos)
    {
        Morris.Line
        ({
          // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
          element: columna,
          // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
          // the chart.
          data: JSON.parse(datos),
          xkey: 'date',
          ykeys: ["value"],
          labels: [columna],
        });
    }
);
}

mostrarGrafico('TotalMembers');
mostrarGrafico('ActiveMembers');
mostrarGrafico('TimeWeek');
mostrarGrafico('TotalTime');
mostrarGrafico('RegWeek');
```

GetStats.php:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
$columna = $_GET['column'];

$sqlstats = "SELECT * FROM statistics";
$resultstats = mysqli_query($con, $sqlstats);
$countstats = mysqli_num_rows($resultstats);

$lista = array();
while($rowstats = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstats))
    $lista[] = array('date' => $rowstats['Date'], 'value' => $rowstats[$columna]);

echo json_encode($lista);
?>
```